# What h264 encoder should I use as a gstreamer pipe on Mac?

Tags: macos, gstreamer

On Mac OS X, I've installed all the gstreamer plugins as far as I'm aware using:

`brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-ffmpeg010`

I am trying to turn a series of photos from a time-lapse into an .mp4 using the following gstreamer pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e multifilesrc location="image_%04d.jpg" ! image/jpeg, framerate=12/1 ! decodebin ! video/x-raw, width=1296, height=976 ! progressreport name=progress ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=15000000 control-rate=variable ! video/x-h264, profile=high ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4`

When I run the command I get the error:

`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "omxh264enc"`

Is there an h264 encoding pipeline available for Mac OS X that can complete this pipeline, or a way to install `omxh264enc`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install gst-libav package and use one of avenc_* plugins. E.g. avenc_mpeg4. It is a sort of software encoders, whereas omxh264 stands for HW encoder.